# locating points on ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, matrix

I tried using `ContourPlot` to plot a curve of $\omega$ vs $k$. $\omega$ and $k$ are related implicitly by the determinant of a 4x4 matrix `Mat`, and I am essentially solving

```
ContoutPlot[Det[Mat[Omega,k]]==0,{k,0,0.5},{Omega,0,0.5}]
```

How do I locate the coordinates of a particular point on the contour line, say $(k=0.5,\omega)$? I tried the 'Get Coordinates' by right-clicking the graphics, but it is not accurate, and I want to know the exact point the computer uses for drawing the contour line.

I also tried using

```
Solve[Det[Mat[Omega,0.5]]==0, Omega]
```

But I get the error `Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.`, and I guess that's because the matrix is a bit complicated.

Are there any ways to get around this?

Comment: Without `Omega` it is hard to say but try `Solve[{Det[Mat[Omega, 1/2]] == 0, 0 <= k <= 1/2}, Omega, Reals]` or  `NSolve[{Det[Mat[Omega, 1/2]] == 0, 0 <= k <= 1/2}, Omega, Reals]`

Comment: My previous comment should read "Without `Mat`..."

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, `NSolve` works for me, thanks.